# Kingo Root fails and gives error code 0x11f116 (Xiaomi Redmi Note 9)

Tags: rooting, xiaomi, application-error, kingo

I unlocked bootloader on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 and tried to Root it with Kingo Root mobile and desktop. Both keep failing and mobile gives error code 0x11f116. Now mobile version crashes when lauching. I couldn't find any information about that code, so can anyone help?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/3985#issuecomment-792006688

Comment: Ok, it helped, thx.