# How do you root a merlinnfc? (Redmi note 9/10X 4G)

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, twrp, xiaomi

Hey there people of this.. site.
I've tried every "Real" method of rooting xiaomi 11.0.5 (My current ROM)
I've tried patched vbmeta images, TWRP, and all of the one click root apps ( Yes my antivirus did flag all of them), and I mean ALL of them. Kingo root, king root, whatever.

I've tried 2 TWRP methods:

The official one: I flashed the recovery partition with the "merlin" image (Yes this did in-fact worked, and my OEM is unlocked btw)
Result: The recovery partition DID NOT BOOT. simply stayed at ADB recovery for a while and rebooted.

An un-official method: I flashed 3 main partitions. Vbmeta, Misc, and recovery. The result? A firm-brick. Somewhere in between in severity of a soft / hard brick. What I mean by this is that it booted and just.. stayed black. There wasn't even a post screen saying "REDMI Powered By Android", luckily it somehow went into ADB recovery allowing me to go into fastboot and flashing the stock global ROM. And.. it worked, thank God.

Other recovery ROMS don't seem to support this device (merlinnfc) like orange fox for example.

In a sense, I've tried everything, and I am yet to defeat the 2020 November security patch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kingo Root fails and gives error code 0x11f116 (Xiaomi Redmi Note 9)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234709/kingo-root-fails-and-gives-error-code-0x11f116-xiaomi-redmi-note-9)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Team Win Recovery Project and Root Xiaomi Redmi Note 9](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233410/how-to-install-team-win-recovery-project-and-root-xiaomi-redmi-note-9)